# счетчик вызова функции python в robot framework

Tags: python, selenium, global-variables

Всем привет! 
Весьма шапошно знаком с python и robot framework поэтому могу пуаться в терминах.
Заранее извиняюсь)
Недавно пришел на стажировку в QA отдел одной организации, где присоединился к работе над существующим проектом, поэтому тонкости структуры этого проекта для меня загадка.

Суть впроса такова:

Работаю над тест кейсом в RF, котоый использует в качестве ключевых слов методы написанные на Python.
Частью кейса является то, что на странице веб приложения нужно выбрать из списка dropdown элемент, на основании его индекса в этом листе.
Я реализовал это с помошью параметра, котоый отправляется в функию при вызове.
НО
Мне нужно модифицировать эту функцию так, чтобы функция вызывалась без параметров, т.е. чтобы при каждом вызове ключевого слова из ТЕСТ КЕЙСА индекс элемента В ФУНКЦИИ PYTHON увеличивался на 1
Я использовал глобальную переменную  ${AccountIndex}=1 в файле Resources/Configuration.robot (там прописаны все глобальные переменные проекта)
У меня получилось увеличить индекс на 1 внутри функции, но при повторном вызове он опять равен 1.
Выходит, я могу считать значение глобальной переменной, но не могу его переписать.

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне это сделать.

как было:

```
def fill_final_registration_form(self, index):
    """Filling the values in final account creation form
    By index select the account from list.
    Value of 'index' is from 1 to 6) """

    try:
        self.common_kw.select_from_dropdown_by_index(ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SELECT, index)
        password = self.builtin.get_variable_value("${USER.Password}")
        self.common_kw.input_text(CREATE_A_PASSWORD, password)
        self.common_kw.input_text(CONFIRM_THE_PASSWORD, password)
        self.selenium_lib.click_element(READ_AND_ACCEPT_CHECKBOX)
    except:
        self.selenium_lib.capture_page_screenshot()
        raise AssertionError("Filling registration form failed.")

    self.selenium_lib.click_element(REGISTRATION_CONTINUE_BUTTON)
```

как стало:

```
def fill_final_registration_form(self):
    """Filling the values in final account creation form
    By index select the account from list.
    Value of 'index' is from 1 to 6) """

    try:
        account_index = int(self.builtin.get_variable_value("${AccountIndex}")) 
        if account_index in range(7):                    
            self.common_kw.select_from_dropdown_by_index(ACCOUNT_NUMBER_SELECT, str(account_index))
            password = self.builtin.get_variable_value("${USER.Password}")
            self.common_kw.input_text(CREATE_A_PASSWORD, password)
            self.common_kw.input_text(CONFIRM_THE_PASSWORD, password)
            self.selenium_lib.click_element(READ_AND_ACCEPT_CHECKBOX)
            account_index += 1
            self.builtin.set_global_variable("${AccountIndex}", str(account_index))
            #self.builtin.evaluate("${AccountIndex}", "${AccountIndex}+1")
                #self.builtin.set_variable("${AccountIndex} + 1")

        else:
            print("All accounts are already in use. Restoring index to the default value(1)")
            account_index = 1
            self.builtin.set_global_variable("${AccoutIndex}", str(account_index))

    except:
        self.selenium_lib.capture_page_screenshot()
        raise AssertionError("Filling registration form failed.")

    self.selenium_lib.click_element(REGISTRATION_CONTINUE_BUTTON)
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно - нужно увеличивать в рамках одного набора тестов или вообще глобально ( т.е. скажем через год значение может достигнуть 25000)?

Comment: Вообще глобально, чтобы при вызове ключевого слова из любого test suite значение индекса было разным. Насчет 2500: когда получится наладить увеличение переменной, нужно добавить условие ограничивающее макс значение, но это уже друго вопрос

Comment: А для чего это? Ведь когда значение дойдёт до максимального, оно на нем и остановится.

Comment: на данный момент проблема в том, что оно вообще не меняется

Comment: Да понятно, что не меняется. Ведь нужно новое значение сохранить в файл, если все время считывать 1, то только 1 и будет. Какую задачу решаете? Возможно, вы пытаетесь забивать гвозди телескопом, тогда как совсем рядом лежит молоток.

Comment: как я уже попытался описать, мне нужно выбрать элемент из dropdown и нужно, чтобы при каждом вызове ключевого слова элемент был разным.

Comment: Я пробовал создавать глоб. переменную внутри самого файла python, в котором находится метод и внутри метода ее менять, т.е. и не использовать set global variable. Результат тот же: каждый раз я получаю одно и то же значение.

Comment: я пробовал создать отдельный метод, который меняет индекс и использовать его внутри метода fill registration form. Не сработало.

Comment: Уверен, что есть каке-то простое решение этой проблемы, но я не могу его найти

Comment: Берите просто случайное число из нужного диапазона.

Comment: случайное не подходит, тк рандом может выбрать число, которое уже было выбрано раньше

Comment: Так в любом случае рано или поздно у вас будет число которое было раньше.